# What is Bdsk-Url-1?

Tags: bibliographies

In my bibliography entries (copied from somewhere on the Web or introduced by a past collaborator) I sometimes discover the field `Bdsk-Url-1`, e.g.,

```
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02485815}
```

What application uses this field and with what semantics?  If, for some Internet resource location , I discover both `Bdsk-Url-1 = {}` and `url = {}`, can I remove the former? If, for some URL , I discover `Bdsk-Url-1 = {}` but not `url = {}`, can I change `Bdsk-Url-1 = {}` to `url = {}`?

Comment: I would imagine it is the artifact of a conversion (bibdesk?) just saving data by dumping url in the original to an unknown bibtex field if it has no defined conversion.

Comment: you know more about the applications you use to handle bib entries than we do.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I sometimes copy the bibtex entries from somewhere on the Web, with fields unknown to me. Or a collaborator provides me with such an entry. Years later, I have no idea where these fields comes from.

Comment: extra fields are not an error but essentially comments, so if you picked up some bib file where someone once added `wibble={foobar}`  it could mean anything or nothing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle After a more extensive Web search, it indeed seems like Bibdesk is using this field for whichever purposes. I've never used bibdesk myself, therefore the confusion.